# Execute batch file on computerA to open excel file and trigger macro on computerB

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, macros

So basically, the reason why I need this is because we can't install excel in the server, so we will have to use another server(computerB) to host all our excel files and macro.

Current process is SSIS will call that batch file on (computerA) where it will call the vbs file on (computerB) so that the excel will open on (computerB) and the macro will be trigger because of the workbook_open event.

Note: computerA doesn't have excel installed so we need to make sure that excel will be open on computerB.

Comment: Why would it be impossible to open the excelsheet from Computer B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PSexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to execute a remote .bat file on ComputerB

Example. *Execute this from ComputerA*

```
psexec -u admin -p Pass123 \\192.168.1.103 -s -d cmd.exe /c "C:\Windows\Test.bat"
```

Name of Batch file. **Test.bat**
User and Pass **admin** and **Pass123**

Location is  **C:\Windows**

> -s         Run remote process in the SYSTEM account (use with caution).
>
> -d         Don’t wait for the application to terminate.
>                 Only use for non-interactive applications.
>
> /C        Carries out the command.
>
> Cmd.exe     Starts the .bat
>
> 192.168.1.103   Example Ip of the Computer.

Comment: Hi @NetworkKingPin, thank you for your answer. I tried proposing your answer to my boss but then she declined it because she doesn't want to use an open source software to our server. In any case, do you have any more suggestion?

Comment: @LeaMonicaLubi I will update my answer accordingly. Is there some guidelines you are looking for? And is this to be only for in house use? or are you trying to get it usable as a application for release to public?